# How to use AppRole authentication for Vault using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

In my application we are making two calls from my app for getting secrets from Vault, as shown below:

1. Login to Vault : POST call to https::/v1/auth/approle/login  -- It will take role_id and secret_id as payload and response will be client_token.
2. Fetch secrets : GET call to https::/v1/secret/data/abc/dev/xyz.json -- It will take headers as X-Vault-Token and X-Vault-Namespace and it will give you the response as below:

   {
   "request_id": "......",
   "lease_id": "",
   "renewable": false,
   "lease_duration": 0,
   "data": {
   "data": {
   "name": "ABC"
   },
   "metadata": {
   "created_time": "...",
   "deletion_time": "",
   "destroyed": false,
   "version": 1
   }
   }

Now I want to use Spring Cloud Vault Dependency to make things work through it. Please provide me the proper illustrations to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are running spring boot and have a working Vault server configured for your app.

Add spring cloud vault maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Add vault configuration to bootstrap.yaml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: abc
  cloud:
    vault:
      host: <vault-server-hostname>
      port: <vault-server-port>
      scheme: HTTPS
      namespace: <name-of-vault-namespace>
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: <your-application-role-id>
        secret-id: <your-application-secret-id>
        role: <your-application-role>
```

If you run your app with spring profiles, like *dev*, it will be picked up and added to the vault path.

Now you should be able to inject secrets stored on the path `secret/data/abc/dev` with `@Value("${<name-of-property>}`

Comment: Is it me or storing role-id AND secret-id in version control isn't considered a proper practice? Wouldn't it be a better idea to inject these through environment variables?

Comment: No, it's not you. It is a bad practice to store it in version control.

Comment: So the solution would be, create a configuration bean, read the role id and secret id from the environment variables and pass them to the configuration bean.